# Using XMLNamespaces in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a file received from customer.
I tried everything to go over the namespace in the file.
Always getting Null value. If I remove everything after Report in the header, it works fine.
I tried WITH XMLNamespaces in many different ways without success.
Please help me having this script working:

```
DECLARE @data XML; 
SET @data =
                '<Report xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="Support_x0020_Contract_x0020_Estimate" xsi:schemaLocation="Support_x0020_Contract_x0020_Estimate http://iomlkfsqlp08.corp.com/ReportServer?%2FIT%20Operations%2FSupport%20Contract%20Estimate&amp;rs%3ACommand=Render&amp;rs%3AFormat=XML&amp;rs%3ASessionID=t3f0mu45i0embcmvkcoardad&amp;rc%3ASchema=True" Name="Support Contract Estimate">
                  <table3 textbox44="249161.2050" textbox64="249161.20500000">
                    <table3_Group1_Collection>
                      <table3_Group1 textbox38="Q.I.T. - Fer et Titane Inc. - Customer Site ID: 16849&#xA;1625 Marie-Victorin&#xA;Tracy, Quebec  J3R 1M6             &#xA;CANADA&#xA;(450) 746-3000&#xA;&#xA;CF Agreement#: 32466&#xA;Percentage Support - Standard Support Level&#xA;Start Date: 17-Jan-2021 - End Date: 16-Jan-2022&#xA; ">
                        <Detail_Collection>
                          <Detail textbox42="Q.I.T. - Fer et Titane Inc. - Customer Site ID: 16849&#xA;1625 Marie-Victorin&#xA;Tracy, Quebec  J3R 1M6             &#xA;CANADA&#xA;(450) 746-3000&#xA;&#xA;CF Agreement#: 32466&#xA;Percentage Support - Standard Support Level&#xA;Start Date: 17-Jan-2021 - End Date: 16-Jan-2022&#xA; " />
                          <Detail textbox42="CF Agreement Net Price" textbox46="245523.4050" textbox63="245523.40500000" />
                        </Detail_Collection>
                      </table3_Group1>
                    </table3_Group1_Collection>
                  </table3>
                  <table5>
                    <table4_Group3_Collection>
                      <table4_Group3 pricingresult1="Q.I.T. - Fer et Titane Inc. - Customer Site ID: 16849&#xA;1625 Marie-Victorin&#xA;Tracy, Quebec  J3R 1M6             &#xA;CANADA&#xA;(450) 746-3000&#xA;&#xA;CF Agreement#: 32466&#xA;Percentage Support - Standard Support Level&#xA;Start Date: 17-Jan-2021 - End Date: 16-Jan-2022&#xA; &#xD;" Textbox11="1 USD:&#xD;1.0000 USD" textbox72="2403700.0000" Textbox135="245523.4050" Textbox18="245523.40500000">
                        <table4_Group4_Collection>
                          <table4_Group4 textbox68="CF-STANDRD-R-HST" textbox69="772685.0000" pricingmethodtiermultiplier="0.17" Textbox104="131356.45" renewalvolumediscount="0.399999999999999" Textbox112="78813.8700000001" Textbox17="78813.8700000001" />
                          <table4_Group4 textbox68="CF-STANDRD-R-MES" textbox69="10485.0000" pricingmethodtiermultiplier="0.225" Textbox104="2359.125" renewalvolumediscount="0.4" Textbox112="1415.475" Textbox17="1415.475" />
                          <table4_Group4 textbox68="CF-STANDRD-R-WW" textbox69="1620530.0000" pricingmethodtiermultiplier="0.170000000000001" Textbox104="275490.100000002" renewalvolumediscount="0.400000000000004" Textbox112="165294.06" Textbox17="165294.06" />
                        </table4_Group4_Collection>
                        <table4>
                          <table4_Group2_Collection>
                            <table4_Group2>
                              <table4_Group1_Collection>
                                <table4_Group1>
                                  <Detail_Collection>
                                    <Detail textbox15="Renewal Volume Discount (40.00%)" textbox16="-163682.2700" Textbox61="-163682.27000000" />
                                  </Detail_Collection>
                                </table4_Group1>
                                <table4_Group1>
                                  <Detail_Collection>
                                    <Detail textbox15="CF Agreement Net Price" textbox16="245523.4050" Textbox61="245523.40500000" />
                                  </Detail_Collection>
                                </table4_Group1>
                                <table4_Group1>
                                  <Detail_Collection>
                                    <Detail textbox15="Cost to upgrade to Premium ($43,235.15)" textbox16="288758.5500" Textbox61="288758.55000000" />
                                    <Detail textbox15="Cost to upgrade to Elite ($86,501.75)" textbox16="332025.1500" Textbox61="332025.15000000" />
                                  </Detail_Collection>
                                </table4_Group1>
                              </table4_Group1_Collection>
                            </table4_Group2>
                          </table4_Group2_Collection>
                        </table4>
                        <table6 Textbox9="3RD PARTY PRODUCT FOR CUSTOMER SITE ID: 16849">
                          <table4_Group5_Collection>
                            <table4_Group5 Textbox12="1 USD:&#xD;1.0000 USD" textbox76="20210.0000" Textbox116="3637.8000" Textbox20="3637.80000000">
                              <table4_Group6_Collection>
                                <table4_Group6 textbox73="10-7008R" textbox74="20210.0000" pricingmethodtiermultiplier2="0.18" Textbox107="3637.8" renewalvolumediscount2="0" Textbox115="3637.8" Textbox19="3637.8" />
                              </table4_Group6_Collection>
                            </table4_Group5>
                          </table4_Group5_Collection>
                        </table6>
                      </table4_Group3>
                    </table4_Group3_Collection>
                  </table5>
                  <table2 />
                  <table1>
                    <table1_Group1_Collection>
                      <table1_Group1 textbox7="PRICING DETAIL BY LICENSE FOR CUSTOMER SITE ID: 16849 - CFA#: 32466" textbox3="1 USD:&#xD;1.0000 USD" listprice_csequiv_1="2423910.0000" textbox4="2423910.00000000">
                        <Detail_Collection>
                          <Detail sw_ser_no="408997-13" sw_sell_part_no="InTch-06-C-20" sw_part_desc="UpgC, InTouch HMI 2020 Wrkst 60000 Tag with I/O" numofconcurusers="1" listprice_csequiv="6490.0000" pricingmethodid2="WW HMI SCADA" intropricingflag="No" create_date="2020-11-25T07:45:26.6" pricingvalue="6490.00000000" />
                          <Detail sw_ser_no="408998-13" sw_sell_part_no="InTch-06-C-20" sw_part_desc="UpgC, InTouch HMI 2020 Wrkst 60000 Tag with I/O" numofconcurusers="1" listprice_csequiv="6490.0000" pricingmethodid2="WW HMI SCADA" intropricingflag="No" create_date="2020-11-25T07:45:26.66" pricingvalue="6490.00000000" />
                          <Detail sw_ser_no="408999-13" sw_sell_part_no="InTch-06-C-20" sw_part_desc="UpgC, InTouch HMI 2020 Wrkst 60000 Tag with I/O" numofconcurusers="1" listprice_csequiv="6490.0000" pricingmethodid2="WW HMI SCADA" intropricingflag="No" create_date="2020-11-25T07:45:26.72" pricingvalue="6490.00000000" />
                          <Detail sw_ser_no="409000-13" sw_sell_part_no="InTch-06-C-20" sw_part_desc="UpgC, InTouch HMI 2020 Wrkst 60000 Tag with I/O" numofconcurusers="1" listprice_csequiv="6490.0000" pricingmethodid2="WW HMI SCADA" intropricingflag="No" create_date="2020-11-25T07:45:26.783" pricingvalue="6490.00000000" />
                          <Detail sw_ser_no="416268-14" sw_sell_part_no="InTDev-01-C-20" sw_part_desc="UpgC, Dev Studio 2020 Limited InTouch Dev/RT 64Tag" numofconcurusers="1" listprice_csequiv="940.0000" pricingmethodid2="WW HMI SCADA" intropricingflag="No" create_date="2020-07-30T07:31:46.553" pricingvalue="940.00000000" />
                        </Detail_Collection>
                      </table1_Group1>
                    </table1_Group1_Collection>
                  </table1>
                </Report>';
---WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT'xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')
SELECT  @data.value('(Report/table1/table1_Group1_Collection/table1_Group1/Detail_Collection/Detail/@sw_ser_no)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as sw_ser_no
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Using MS SQL 2012. I fixed the issue for Namespaces. Now I am looking to have all records back not only the first one. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Your default namespace is `'Support_x0020_Contract_x0020_Estimate'`

```
DECLARE @data XML; 
SET @data =
                '<Report xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="Support_x0020_Contract_x0020_Estimate" xsi:schemaLocation="Support_x0020_Contract_x0020_Estimate http://iomlkfsqlp08.corp.com/ReportServer?%2FIT%20Operations%2FSupport%20Contract%20Estimate&amp;rs%3ACommand=Render&amp;rs%3AFormat=XML&amp;rs%3ASessionID=t3f0mu45i0embcmvkcoardad&amp;rc%3ASchema=True" Name="Support Contract Estimate">
                  <table3 textbox44="249161.2050" textbox64="249161.20500000">
                    <table3_Group1_Collection>
                      <table3_Group1 textbox38="Q.I.T. - Fer et Titane Inc. - Customer Site ID: 16849&#xA;1625 Marie-Victorin&#xA;Tracy, Quebec  J3R 1M6             &#xA;CANADA&#xA;(450) 746-3000&#xA;&#xA;CF Agreement#: 32466&#xA;Percentage Support - Standard Support Level&#xA;Start Date: 17-Jan-2021 - End Date: 16-Jan-2022&#xA; ">
                        <Detail_Collection>
                          <Detail textbox42="Q.I.T. - Fer et Titane Inc. - Customer Site ID: 16849&#xA;1625 Marie-Victorin&#xA;Tracy, Quebec  J3R 1M6             &#xA;CANADA&#xA;(450) 746-3000&#xA;&#xA;CF Agreement#: 32466&#xA;Percentage Support - Standard Support Level&#xA;Start Date: 17-Jan-2021 - End Date: 16-Jan-2022&#xA; " />
                          <Detail textbox42="CF Agreement Net Price" textbox46="245523.4050" textbox63="245523.40500000" />
                        </Detail_Collection>
                      </table3_Group1>
                    </table3_Group1_Collection>
                  </table3>
                  <table5>
                    <table4_Group3_Collection>
                      <table4_Group3 pricingresult1="Q.I.T. - Fer et Titane Inc. - Customer Site ID: 16849&#xA;1625 Marie-Victorin&#xA;Tracy, Quebec  J3R 1M6             &#xA;CANADA&#xA;(450) 746-3000&#xA;&#xA;CF Agreement#: 32466&#xA;Percentage Support - Standard Support Level&#xA;Start Date: 17-Jan-2021 - End Date: 16-Jan-2022&#xA; &#xD;" Textbox11="1 USD:&#xD;1.0000 USD" textbox72="2403700.0000" Textbox135="245523.4050" Textbox18="245523.40500000">
                        <table4_Group4_Collection>
                          <table4_Group4 textbox68="CF-STANDRD-R-HST" textbox69="772685.0000" pricingmethodtiermultiplier="0.17" Textbox104="131356.45" renewalvolumediscount="0.399999999999999" Textbox112="78813.8700000001" Textbox17="78813.8700000001" />
                          <table4_Group4 textbox68="CF-STANDRD-R-MES" textbox69="10485.0000" pricingmethodtiermultiplier="0.225" Textbox104="2359.125" renewalvolumediscount="0.4" Textbox112="1415.475" Textbox17="1415.475" />
                          <table4_Group4 textbox68="CF-STANDRD-R-WW" textbox69="1620530.0000" pricingmethodtiermultiplier="0.170000000000001" Textbox104="275490.100000002" renewalvolumediscount="0.400000000000004" Textbox112="165294.06" Textbox17="165294.06" />
                        </table4_Group4_Collection>
                        <table4>
                          <table4_Group2_Collection>
                            <table4_Group2>
                              <table4_Group1_Collection>
                                <table4_Group1>
                                  <Detail_Collection>
                                    <Detail textbox15="Renewal Volume Discount (40.00%)" textbox16="-163682.2700" Textbox61="-163682.27000000" />
                                  </Detail_Collection>
                                </table4_Group1>
                                <table4_Group1>
                                  <Detail_Collection>
                                    <Detail textbox15="CF Agreement Net Price" textbox16="245523.4050" Textbox61="245523.40500000" />
                                  </Detail_Collection>
                                </table4_Group1>
                                <table4_Group1>
                                  <Detail_Collection>
                                    <Detail textbox15="Cost to upgrade to Premium ($43,235.15)" textbox16="288758.5500" Textbox61="288758.55000000" />
                                    <Detail textbox15="Cost to upgrade to Elite ($86,501.75)" textbox16="332025.1500" Textbox61="332025.15000000" />
                                  </Detail_Collection>
                                </table4_Group1>
                              </table4_Group1_Collection>
                            </table4_Group2>
                          </table4_Group2_Collection>
                        </table4>
                        <table6 Textbox9="3RD PARTY PRODUCT FOR CUSTOMER SITE ID: 16849">
                          <table4_Group5_Collection>
                            <table4_Group5 Textbox12="1 USD:&#xD;1.0000 USD" textbox76="20210.0000" Textbox116="3637.8000" Textbox20="3637.80000000">
                              <table4_Group6_Collection>
                                <table4_Group6 textbox73="10-7008R" textbox74="20210.0000" pricingmethodtiermultiplier2="0.18" Textbox107="3637.8" renewalvolumediscount2="0" Textbox115="3637.8" Textbox19="3637.8" />
                              </table4_Group6_Collection>
                            </table4_Group5>
                          </table4_Group5_Collection>
                        </table6>
                      </table4_Group3>
                    </table4_Group3_Collection>
                  </table5>
                  <table2 />
                  <table1>
                    <table1_Group1_Collection>
                      <table1_Group1 textbox7="PRICING DETAIL BY LICENSE FOR CUSTOMER SITE ID: 16849 - CFA#: 32466" textbox3="1 USD:&#xD;1.0000 USD" listprice_csequiv_1="2423910.0000" textbox4="2423910.00000000">
                        <Detail_Collection>
                          <Detail sw_ser_no="408997-13" sw_sell_part_no="InTch-06-C-20" sw_part_desc="UpgC, InTouch HMI 2020 Wrkst 60000 Tag with I/O" numofconcurusers="1" listprice_csequiv="6490.0000" pricingmethodid2="WW HMI SCADA" intropricingflag="No" create_date="2020-11-25T07:45:26.6" pricingvalue="6490.00000000" />
                          <Detail sw_ser_no="408998-13" sw_sell_part_no="InTch-06-C-20" sw_part_desc="UpgC, InTouch HMI 2020 Wrkst 60000 Tag with I/O" numofconcurusers="1" listprice_csequiv="6490.0000" pricingmethodid2="WW HMI SCADA" intropricingflag="No" create_date="2020-11-25T07:45:26.66" pricingvalue="6490.00000000" />
                          <Detail sw_ser_no="408999-13" sw_sell_part_no="InTch-06-C-20" sw_part_desc="UpgC, InTouch HMI 2020 Wrkst 60000 Tag with I/O" numofconcurusers="1" listprice_csequiv="6490.0000" pricingmethodid2="WW HMI SCADA" intropricingflag="No" create_date="2020-11-25T07:45:26.72" pricingvalue="6490.00000000" />
                          <Detail sw_ser_no="409000-13" sw_sell_part_no="InTch-06-C-20" sw_part_desc="UpgC, InTouch HMI 2020 Wrkst 60000 Tag with I/O" numofconcurusers="1" listprice_csequiv="6490.0000" pricingmethodid2="WW HMI SCADA" intropricingflag="No" create_date="2020-11-25T07:45:26.783" pricingvalue="6490.00000000" />
                          <Detail sw_ser_no="416268-14" sw_sell_part_no="InTDev-01-C-20" sw_part_desc="UpgC, Dev Studio 2020 Limited InTouch Dev/RT 64Tag" numofconcurusers="1" listprice_csequiv="940.0000" pricingmethodid2="WW HMI SCADA" intropricingflag="No" create_date="2020-07-30T07:31:46.553" pricingvalue="940.00000000" />
                        </Detail_Collection>
                      </table1_Group1>
                    </table1_Group1_Collection>
                  </table1>
                </Report>';
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'Support_x0020_Contract_x0020_Estimate')
SELECT  @data.value('(Report/table1/table1_Group1_Collection/table1_Group1/Detail_Collection/Detail/@sw_ser_no)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as sw_ser_no
```

Returns

```
sw_ser_no
408997-13
```

**Edit**

Extract all items as nodes:

```
...
SELECT t.n.value('(@sw_ser_no)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as sw_ser_no 
FROM @data.nodes('Report/table1/table1_Group1_Collection/table1_Group1/Detail_Collection/Detail') t(n)
```

Comment: One more quick question, this only retrieve the first serial number. How could I retrieve all SN ?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this blog. Saw your answer Serge. All good now querying with nodes. Thank you all